# FillingStyle colour scheme mathematica ListPlot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to create an interactive plot of xray energies of specific elements.

To do this I have created a bunch of x,y points(representing xray energies for each element and an arbitrary y-value). I have then used ListPlot with Filling ->Axis to create visible lines. All good except that "Filling" uses the default beige colour scheme to label each element. This is very hard to read/compare. When I try to use "FillingStyle -> blah" to change the colour scheme, thickness, opacity etc. the plot crashes or defaults to black for all elements.

The only options that work are to change all the fills to "Blue" for example (doesn't really help me compare and contrast elements). I've also tried modifying PlotStyle but it seems to have no effect in the filling (not surprised - but it would have been nice).

```
 Manipulate[
 Grid[{
   {(*grid group 1*)
    Show[
     {
      ListPlot[
       {mNe ne, mNa na, mMg mg, mAm am},
       Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Blue, PlotMarkers -> {""}, 
       AspectRatio -> .25, ImageSize -> 500, AxesLabel -> {"eV", ""}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 20000}, {0, 1}}
       ]
      }
     ], "Full View"}}
  ],
 {{mNe, 1, "Ne"}, {0, 1}, Checkbox},
 {{mNa, 0, "Na"}, {0, 1}, Checkbox},
 {{mMg, 0, "Mg"}, {0, 1}, Checkbox},
 {{mAm, 1, "Am"}, {0, 1}, Checkbox}]
```

Obviously this code won't compile because I Havent provided you with the original data. I'm new to this forum so I can't yet post a screen grab. sorry.

So the end goal is to have each element displayed with a unique (high contrast colour). I don't wan't to have to specify a colour for each element (93 to plot!).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the filling for each data set within the `Filling` option, like this:

```
{one, two, three} = 
  Table[{RandomReal[30, 30], RandomReal[1, 30]}\[Transpose], {3}];

ListPlot[{one, two, three}, PlotStyle -> None, AspectRatio -> .25,
  Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, Red}, 2 -> {Axis, Darker@Green}, 3 -> {Axis, Blue}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From More Information in [the documentation for `Filling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Filling.html):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks Mr Wizard. I was hoping to be able to apply a colour scheme rather than specify each one. Cheers.

Comment: @Grrwebb you could generate the style list programmatically.  Do you need help with that?

Comment: Hi Mr Wizard, sorry for the late reply. It would be great to know how to do such things. i'm worried that it might go over my a head a little...